# Assignment throws error in cool

Tags: syntax

Compilation of this program throws

**compilers@compilers-vm:~/cool/jim$** coolc list.cl
*"list.cl", line 7: syntax error at or near ';'

Compilation halted due to lex and parse errors*

```
class List{
    item : String;
    next : List;

    init(i: String, n: List) : List 
    {
        item <- i;
        next <- n;

        self
    };

    flattn(): String 
    {
        if( isvoid next )
            then 
                item
            else
                item.concat( next.flattn())
            fi
    };
};

class Main inherits IO {

    main() : Object{
            let hello : String <- "Hello ",
                wold : String <- "world ",
                newLine : String <- "\n",
                unfedined : List,
                l : List <- (new List).init(hello,
                                (new List).init(wold, 
                                    (new List).init(newLine, unfedined ) ) )

            in 
                out_string( l.flattn() )

    };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a block that returns a value for init method. 
here

```
      item <- i;
      next <- n;
      self;
```

.. must be wrapped in to a block;

```
init(i: String, n: List) : List 
        {
            {
              item <- i;
              next <- n;

            self;
            }     
   };
```